# How do I use values from a .h file for calculations in a .c file?

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate values in rand.h:

```
#ifndef RAND_H_INCLUDED
#define RAND_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
double rando()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    double base=rand(); /*using base instead of time because of random generator using the built-in time function*/
    double height[20];
    double pressure[20];
    /*random heights*/
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        height[i]=rand();
    }
    /*random pressures*/
    int q;
    for(q=0;q<20;q++){
        pressure[q]=rand();
    }
}
#endif // RAND_H_INCLUDED
```

And then use them for the calculations in main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "rand.h"
int main() /*table formatting testing*/
{
    rando();
    double base;
    double height;
    double pressure;
    int hnum=sizeof(height)/sizeof(height[0]);
    int pnum=sizeof(pressure)/sizeof(pressure[0]);
    /*printing height*/
    int hloop;
    for (hloop=0;hloop<hnum;hloop++){
      if (hloop==0){
        printf("     %g",height[hloop]);
      }  else{
        printf(" %g",height[hloop]);
    }
    }
    /*printing time and pressure*/
    printf("\n");
    int ploop;
    for (ploop=0;ploop<pnum;ploop++){
     if (ploop==0){
        printf("%g %g",base,pressure[ploop]);
     }   else{
        printf(" %g",pressure[ploop]);
     }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get multiple errors from rand.h and main.c. From rand.h I get the both pressure and height are set but not used, and that base is unused. From main.c I get a bunch of errors saying that pressure and height aren't arrays, pointers, or vectors. How do I use the values calculated in rand.h for the calculations in main.c. *Note that the values must be calculated in rand.h then somehow transferred to main.c*.

Comment: `double height;` in main.c is indeed not an array.

Comment: Don't put executable code in a header file. Only put declarations. The implementation should go in a separate .c file. Also, don't call `srand()` in a library function. It should only be called exactly once, at program startup; library functions should try to avoid that sort of restriction.

Comment: Values can't be transferred from header to c.  Where has that requirement come from?  Including the header file copies it verbatim into the c, but as others have said, it should contain declarations not definitions...

Comment: Not like that. The variables you declare inside the rando() function are allocated on the stack, when the function returns, the values are gone.  declare them in main, then pass in as parameters (using pointers so you can send back the result) to rando()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that the variables `base`, `height`, and `pressure` in the `rando` function are the same ones in the `main` function.  They are not.  Variables declared in a function are local to that function.

This is why you're getting warnings that these variables in `rando` are not used, because they're not being read anywhere in this function.

The errors you get from the `main` function are because `height` and `pressure` are in fact not arrays:

```
double height;
double pressure;
```

You need to change `rando` to take a parameter for each of these three objects:

```
void rando(double *base, double *height, double *pressure)
```

Note also that the return type is changed to `void` because you're not actually returning anything.  Then the body would have the following changes:

```
srand(time(NULL));
*base=rand();    // dereference the given pointer to change base in main
/*random heights*/
```

Then in `main` you would make this change:

```
double base;
double height[20];
double pressure[20];
rando(&base, height, pressure);
```

Note that you need to pass the address of `base` so that it can be changed.  This is not needed on the two arrays as the names are converted to pointers when passed to the function.

On a separate note, it's not a good idea to have function definitions in a header file.  If this header were to be included by more than one .c file, you would get errors about the function being defined multiple times.

The header should only contain a declaration:

```
#ifndef RAND_H_INCLUDED
#define RAND_H_INCLUDED

void rando(double *base, double *height, double *pressure);

#endif // RAND_H_INCLUDED
```

And the body of the function would be in a separate file, i.e. rand.c.  Then you would compile both rand.c and main.c and link them.

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't implement function in .h files, create a separate .c and define it in .h file to use it in an another .c by calling this .h file, it's more readable on large project.

Second point your function isn't returning anything it should be void rando() (It's not a function, it's called a procedure if I'm right on the English name).

And I guess your procedure is made to initialize some random data, so why do you call the function before you initialize the variable ?

The point is that your variable is not even global, so you should have parameter define for calling the function (since they are array you don't need to create pointer)

Answer (score 0):

Try either make rando() of type void...

```
#ifndef RAND_H_INCLUDED
#define RAND_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void rando() //change type void
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    double base=rand(); /*using base instead of time because of random generator using the built-in time function*/
    double height[20];
    double pressure[20];
    /*random heights*/
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        height[i]=rand();
    }
    /*random pressures*/
    int q;
    for(q=0;q<20;q++){
        pressure[q]=rand();
    }
}
#endif // RAND_H_INCLUDED
```

or, just write a return statement,

```
#ifndef RAND_H_INCLUDED
#define RAND_H_INCLUDED
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
double rando()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    double base=rand(); /*using base instead of time because of random generator using the built-in time function*/
    double height[20];
    double pressure[20];
    /*random heights*/
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        height[i]=rand();
    }
    /*random pressures*/
    int q;
    for(q=0;q<20;q++){
        pressure[q]=rand();
    }
return 0; //correction
}
#endif // RAND_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: I really don't think this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `rand.h` declare a `struct` containing all of the values to be initialized by `rando()`
2. Define a structure of this type in `main`
3. Pass the address of this structure to `rando()`
4. In `main()`, use the values with the syntax `structure.member`

Answer (score -1):

What's usually the suggested approach in `C` programming language is to put:

1. Function Declarations in HEADER (.h) files
2. Function Definitions in C (.c) files

So, I would have three files in your case:

1. main.c (with the main function)
2. rand.c (with rando function definition)
3. rand.h (with rando function header)

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "rand.h"

int main() /*table formatting testing*/
{
    rando();
    double base;
    double height;
    double pressure;
    int hnum=sizeof(height)/sizeof(height[0]);
    int pnum=sizeof(pressure)/sizeof(pressure[0]);
    /*printing height*/
    int hloop;
    for (hloop=0;hloop<hnum;hloop++){
      if (hloop==0){
        printf("     %g",height[hloop]);
      }  else{
        printf(" %g",height[hloop]);
    }
    }
    /*printing time and pressure*/
    printf("\n");
    int ploop;
    for (ploop=0;ploop<pnum;ploop++){
     if (ploop==0){
        printf("%g %g",base,pressure[ploop]);
     }   else{
        printf(" %g",pressure[ploop]);
     }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**rand.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "rand.h"

double rando()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    double base=rand(); /*using base instead of time because of random generator using the built-in time function*/
    double height[20];
    double pressure[20];
    /*random heights*/
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        height[i]=rand();
    }
    /*random pressures*/
    int q;
    for(q=0;q<20;q++){
        pressure[q]=rand();
    }
}
```

**rand.h**

```
#ifndef RAND_H_INCLUDED
#define RAND_H_INCLUDED
double rando();
#endif // RAND_H_INCLUDED
```

=======

After all these, you write a `Makefile` for your build process. But if you want to compile everything by hand, you can do:

```
$ gcc -c rand.c
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gcc rand.o main.o -o main
$ ./main
```

But, **do keep in mind** that your code does not compile. It has some errors (such us using `pressure` (or `height`) as a global array although it's just a local `double` variable inside `main` function.

Comment: This doesn't address the question of how the user code in `main()` is going to access the values initialized in `rando()`.